# Regex: Match from character to end of line without the last match group

Tags: javascript, regex, uri

I want to extract the `q` param from some urls:

```
.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=test
.com/search?q=something+else&source=123
```

Here's a regex I came up with: `q=(.*?)(&|$)`. When `&` terminates, the results are:

```
["q=test", "test", "&"]
```

otherwise, when it hits the end of line:

```
["q=test", "test", ""]
```

This works but doesn't seem right.

Is there a way to not include the last match group at all, since I'm not interested in it?

Comment: ... Why not just change your regex to `/q=(.*?)[&|$]/` ? You're not looking to match the `&|$`, you're looking to evaluate them as a group.

Comment: @TheIronDeveloper that doesn't match the first url

Comment: @Thelron `[&|$]` would do beyond your assumptions.

Comment: You're right, the pipe did not make sense there. Heres a better regex that does work for both: `/q=([^&]*)/` . Only reason why I am still commenting is look-ahead regexes have poor performance.

Comment: @TheIronDeveloper Interesting, and duly noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn the last group into a positive lookahead assertion.

`(?=&|$)` asserts that the match must be followed by a `&` or end of the line anchor `$`

```
q=(.*?)(?=&|$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yD2hI7/3)

```
> ".com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=test".match(/q=(.*?)(?=&|$)/)
[ 'q=test',
  'test',
  index: 17,
  input: '.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=test' ]
```

To print only the chars inside the captured group.

```
> var s = ".com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=test"
undefined
> console.log(/q=(.*?)(?=&|$)/.exec(s)[1]);
test
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Is there a way to prevent JS from including the first capture group as well? Meaning, only seeing `['test']`?

Comment: Yeah I know how to get it out of the resulting array, I was just curious why JS includes the first match `q=test` and not just the result. I suppose it means "this is what was matched, and here is the result" - I'm just a bit uneasy when accessing an array that potentially can be null

Comment: js prints the match `q=test` as well as the captures `test`. Match is at the index 0 and captures is at the index 1.